# How to remove zero in between section numbering in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

Please how do I remove zero in between section numbering from the table of content. Please see the picture below. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If `Introduction` is a `\section` you need to add a `\subsection{something}` before `\subsubsection{Background of the study}`. If `Introduction` is a `\chapter` you need to add a `\section{something}` before `\subsection{Background of the study}`.

Comment: The 0 should not be there, are you jumping from `\section` to `\subsubsection` with no `\subsection` ???

Comment: See [sectioning - Keep section and subsubsection number, remove subsection - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635383/keep-section-and-subsubsection-number-remove-subsection)

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't keep using `\subsubsection` without `\subsection` you have two options:

- suppress `\subsubsection` numbering with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`
- change the formatting of `\subsubsection` numbers with :

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
  ```