# Keep section and subsubsection number, remove subsection

Tags: sectioning

Due to typographical preference, I want to use **subsubsection** as my **subsection**.  However, I don't want a placeholder with a zero in it for my non-existent subsection numbering.  How can I get rid of the zeros?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section} 
\subsection{Subsection Header Too Big For Me}
\subsubsection{I Want This Numbered as a Subsection}
\section{Other Section} 
\subsubsection{I Don't Want This Zero in the Middle}
\subsubsection{For Example, This Should be ``2.1''}
\section{Third Section} 
\subsubsection{This Should Be Numbered ``3.1''}
\subsubsection{I Don't Want This ``0'' for a Non-Existent Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may consider using packages such as `titlesec` to modify the style of `\subsection` to meet your typographical preference. Here on this site you can find plenty such examples.

Comment: In other words, you would like to have `\subsubsection`s that *for all intents and purposes* work *like* `\subsection`s, except for the heading's font size. Am I reading this right? If this is true, it would open up a different (simpler) kind of solutions. (f.i. you could do what @Jinwen suggested: edit the *typographical looks* of `\subsection`)

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

If its just about typography and the looks of things you could redefine subsection by using:

```
\makeatletter    
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{1}{\z@}%
                                  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                  {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Just substitute **large** with whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this line below, it is solved. I could remove all the zeros between the subsubsection numbering:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do, from a terminal window,

```
latexdef subsection subsubsection`
```

you will get the standard definition for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`

```
\subsection:
\long macro:->\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@ }{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \large \bfseries }

\subsubsection:
\long macro:->\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@ }{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }
```

so you see that the simple difference is the font size. OK, how can you easily fix it? In two ways, neither of which relying on using `\subsubsection` instead of `\subsection`.

#### Method 1: `sectsty`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\section{Section} 
\subsection{I Want This Numbered as a Subsection}
\section{Other Section} 
\subsection{I Don't Want This Zero in the Middle}
\subsection{For Example, This Should be ``2.1''}
\section{Third Section} 
\subsection{This Should Be Numbered ``3.1''}
\subsection{I Don't Want This ``0'' for a Non-Existent Subsection}
\end{document}
```

There are two innocuous warnings.

#### Method 2: `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\subsection}{\large}{\normalsize}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section} 
\subsection{I Want This Numbered as a Subsection}
\section{Other Section} 
\subsection{I Don't Want This Zero in the Middle}
\subsection{For Example, This Should be ``2.1''}
\section{Third Section} 
\subsection{This Should Be Numbered ``3.1''}
\subsection{I Don't Want This ``0'' for a Non-Existent Subsection}
\end{document}
```

#### Output with either method

[image]